# Bounding errors in numerical calculations

Tags: precision, numerical-integration

I have a theoretical math problem where I need to calculate a numerical value and bound its possible range. I can bound the numerical error for all the operations, but since some of them are fairly involved (Taylor expansions, elliptic integrals) I would expect a simple way to do it to already exist (In any language TBH, but python is always a plus).

Can you point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: Just some ideas: Use the condition number of summation/numerical integration, use interval arithmetic, use higher precision and see difference against lower precision.

Comment: Thanks! but I'm actually looking for the provable bound, and not the probable numerical range.

Comment: Probably a question for https://math.stackexchange.com/.